# Delete log files older than X days

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am using Python's `TimedRotatingFileHandler` to create and rotate logs. However, I was wondering is there any inbuilt feature available in `TimedRotatingFileHandler` to delete old logs after certain days OR I have to write a separate Python script to clean logs?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `backupCount` parameter to do that. More info at https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler